# нужна помощь с питоном (скрипт для тг)

Tags: python, telethon

скажу сразу я чайник и только учу питон.
в общем у меня есть скрипт для автоответчика в тг.
и мне нужно сделать так, чтоб когда мне писали, автоответчик отвечал каждому челу только 1 раз, ( как приветственное сообщение )
и больше не реагировал на чела .

может кто-то знает как это сделать?..

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


api_id =
api_hash = ''

client = TelegramClient('user', api_id, api_hash).start()


message = "Hello! Thank you for contacting me \nI'll be back soon and reply to your message."

@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def handler(event):
    sender = await event.get_input_sender()
 
    await client.send_message(sender, message)

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: с такими заказами вам на другой сайт нужно.

Answer (score 0):

клиент телеграма telegraph имеет встроенную функцию автоответчика и не нужно юзербота для этого запускать

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]